# Add column containing number of columns og grouped by df

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, group-by

How can I add a column to a DF with the number of rows using a group By clause?

```
+------------+-------+
|  Category  |  txn  | 
+-----===----+-------+  
|  Cat1      |   A   |  
|  Cat1      |   A   |
|  Cat1      |   B   |
+------------+-------+
```

desired output:

```
+------------+-------+-----+
|  Category  |  txn  |  n  |
+-----===----+-------+-----+  
|  Cat1      |   A   |  2  |
|  Cat1      |   A   |  2  |   
|  Cat1      |   B   |  1  |
+------------+-------+-----+
```

I tried the following:

```
 df.withColumn("n", df.groupBy("Category", "txn").count())
```

and it returned:

```
 type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
    (which expands to)  org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]
 required: org.apache.spark.sql.Column
```

and then

```
df.withColumn("n", df.groupBy("Category", "txn").agg(count()))
```

and it returned:

```
 error: overloaded method value count with alternatives:
  (columnName: String)org.apache.spark.sql.TypedColumn[Any,Long] <and>
  (e: org.apache.spark.sql.Column)org.apache.spark.sql.Column
 cannot be applied to ()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do a count and a join:

```
val df = Seq(("C1","A"),("C1","A"),("C1","B")).toDF("Category", "Txn")

val countDf = df.groupBy(col("Category"), col("Txn")).count
countDf.show
+--------+---+-----+
|Category|Txn|count|
+--------+---+-----+
|      C1|  A|    2|
|      C1|  B|    1|
+--------+---+-----+

df.join(countDf, Seq("Category", "Txn"))
  .withColumnRenamed("count", "n")   
  .show
+--------+---+---+
|Category|Txn|  n|
+--------+---+---+
|      C1|  A|  2|
|      C1|  A|  2|
|      C1|  B|  1|
+--------+---+---+
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Can't we do the groupBy.count directly inside withColumn?

Comment: I don't see a way of doing that without a Window function... if you want to change the name of the column you can use the method withColumnRenamed after the join. I'll edit the answer

Answer (score 2):

```scala
scala> df.show
+--------+---+
|Category|txn|
+--------+---+
|    Cat1|  A|
|    Cat1|  A|
|    Cat1|  B|
+--------+---+

scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

scala> val w = Window.partitionBy("Category","txn").orderBy(col("txn"))

scala> df.withColumn("n", dense_rank.over(w))
         .withColumn("n", sum(col("n")).over(w))
         .show
+--------+---+---+
|Category|txn|  n|
+--------+---+---+
|    Cat1|  B|  1|
|    Cat1|  A|  2|
|    Cat1|  A|  2|
+--------+---+---+
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to achieve what you want is to use a window, partitioned by `txn` and the `count` function. No need to use `groupBy` since you want to keep all the rows of your dataframe. Don't order the window either, it is useless in your case and would slow down the process.

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
val df = Seq(("C1","A"),("C1","A"),("C1","B")).toDF("Category", "Txn")
val w = Window.partitionBy("txn")
df.withColumn("n", count('*) over w).show()
```

Which yields

```
+--------+---+---+
|Category|Txn|  n|
+--------+---+---+
|      C1|  B|  1|
|      C1|  A|  2|
|      C1|  A|  2|
+--------+---+---+
```